# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADD_MONTHS'

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created the below procedure to only retain the last two months data only and delete the rest one against a table in oracle, below is the procedure but i am getting exception, please advise how to overcome from this

```
create or replace package TEST_TABLE AS
   PROCEDURE TEST_TABLE;
END TEST_TABLE;


create or replace PACKAGE BODY TEST_TABLE AS 
 PROCEDURE TEST_TABLE IS        
 BEGIN
  FOR cc IN
  (
  SELECT partition_name, high_value
  FROM user_tab_partitions
  WHERE table_name = 'TEST_TABLE'
  )    
  LOOP
   BEGIN               
     IF sysdate >= ADD_MONTHS(cc.high_value,2) THEN                  
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE                     
      'ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE DROP PARTITION ' || cc.partition_name;                   
       Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Dropping partition is completed.');        
     END IF;
   END;
  END LOOP;

  EXCEPTION WHEN Others THEN Dbms_Output.Put_Line( SQLERRM );

 END TEST_TABLE;

END TEST_TABLE;
```

The error that I am getting is:

> Error(12,6): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   Error(12,20): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADD_MONTHS'

Comment: Your procedure does not accept any parameter. How do you call it?

Comment: Perhaps you need to get month from `sysdate` and then compare to the `ADD_MONTHS(cc.high_value,2)`?

Comment: What is the datatype of `high_value` in `user_tab_partitions`?

Comment: @Bohemian Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (PARTITION_NAME,LAST_ANALYZED,NUM_ROWS,BLOCKS,SAMPLE_SIZE,HIGH_VALUE) values ('JUL2018',to_date('22-FEB-19','DD-MON-RR'),0,0,null,'TO_DATE('' 2018-08-01 00:00:00'', ''SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'', ''NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'')');

Comment: @fkljfklgfjhkgbng so, `high_value` is a text data type containing values like `'TO_DATE('' 2018-08-01 00:00:00'', ''SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'', ''NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'')'`? More simply, can you just tell us the datatype of the `high_value` column? eg it is `varchar`? Others think it's a numeric type. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, It's insane to call table name, package name and procedure name all by `TEST_TABLE` as being done by you, as if there's no other name available. I've named them appropriately.

`HIGH_VALUE` cannot be directly used in `DATE` related functions as it's of `LONG` TYPE. There's a simple method to convert it to date using dynamic SQL(`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`)

```
CREATE OR replace PACKAGE BODY PKG_test_table AS
     PROCEDURE pr_test_table
          IS
          v_high_value DATE;
     BEGIN
          FOR cc IN (
               SELECT partition_name,
                      high_value
               FROM user_tab_partitions
               WHERE table_name = 'TEST_TABLE'
          ) LOOP
               BEGIN
             EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :v_high_val := '|| cc.high_value || '; END;' 
                           USING OUT v_high_value;
                    IF
                         SYSDATE >= add_months(v_high_value,2)
                    THEN
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE DROP PARTITION ' 
           || cc.partition_name;
                         dbms_output.put_line('Dropping partition is completed.');
                    END IF;
               END;
          END LOOP;
     EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
               dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
     END pr_TEST_TABLE;
END PKG_test_table;
/
```

**Calling the procedure**

```
BEGIN 
 PKG_test_table.pr_test_table; 
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks I have complied the procedure it is executed successfully now please advise how to execute the same , please give the calling query to

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure does not accept any parameter. You can't pass any arguments to it.

Comment: Thanks gentle request can you please make changes in my above procedure so that it should take those parameters also

Comment: As I don't know what params you want to add, neither their goal, I won't. Obviously, taking a look at the documentation would not be a waste of time.. You can find an example here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/overview.htm#g1461293

Answer (score 0):

The HIGH_VALUE column from USER_TAB_PARTITIONS is a long data type, I'm not going copy code from another web site, but if you google "oracle convert high value to date" you should get some ideas on how to create a function that you can use to convert the 'long' to a date.

My reputation is too low to post this as a comment, so I added it as an answer, it should help though it is not a good answer :(

Answer (score 0):

As the error says it all ADD_MONTHS takes a DATE and you are passing in as LONG.

Try something like this and it should be ok.

Example:

```
DECLARE
DT LONG(1000) := 'TO_DATE('||''''||'2018-08-01 00:00:00'||''''||',' ||''''|| 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'||''''||','||''''||'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'||''''||')';
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DT);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
             'BEGIN
                 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS('||DT||',2),'||''''||'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'||''''||
              ')); END;';

END;
```

Output:

```
TO_DATE('2018-08-01 00:00:00','SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS','NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
2018-10-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not allow functions over long such as cast, substr, add_months over long type however … read below.

1. Long type

   describe user_tab_partitions;

   ...
   SUBPARTITION_COUNT           NUMBER
   HIGH_VALUE                   LONG
   HIGH_VALUE_LENGTH            NUMBER
   ...
2. Function to convert long to varchar2

   FUNCTION long_to_varchar2 ( p_table_owner IN     VARCHAR2,p_table_name     IN VARCHAR2, p_partition_name IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
   is
   l_tmp long;
   BEGIN

   select high_value 
   into l_tmp 
   from all_tab_partitions 
   where table_owner = p_table_owner
   and table_name = p_table_name
   and partition_name = p_partition_name ;

   RETURN l_tmp;
   END long_to_varchar2;

3.Use your new function

```
select tpar."OWNER",tpar."TABLE_NAME",tpar."PART_MIN",tpar."PART_MIN_HV",tpar."PART_MAX",tpar."PART_MAX_HV",tpar."NR_PART"
      ,pkey.column_name as partitioned_by
      ,ptab.partitioning_type as partition_type
      ,ptab.status  
from        
      (select p1.table_owner     as owner
             ,p1.table_name 
             ,pmin.partition_name as part_min
             ,to_date(substr(long_to_varchar2(p1.table_owner,p1.table_name,pmin.partition_name),11,10),'yyyy-mm-dd') as part_min_hv
             ,pmax.partition_name as part_max
             ,to_date(substr(long_to_varchar2(p1.table_owner,p1.table_name,pmax.partition_name),11,10),'yyyy-mm-dd') as part_max_hv
             ,p1.nr_part+1        as nr_part
       from (select min(part.partition_position) as minp
                   ,max(part.partition_position) as maxp
                   ,count(*)                     as nr_part
                   ,part.table_name
                   ,part.table_owner
             from all_tab_partitions part,
                  dba_tables tbls
             where part.table_name=tbls.table_name
             and part.table_owner=tbls.owner
             and part.PARTITION_NAME <> 'P_CURRENT'
             group by part.table_name, part.table_owner) p1
            ,all_tab_partitions pmin
            ,all_tab_partitions pmax
       where p1.table_name = pmin.table_name
       and p1.table_owner = pmin.table_owner
       and p1.minp=pmin.partition_position
       and p1.table_name = pmax.table_name
       and p1.table_owner = pmax.table_owner
       and p1.maxp = pmax.partition_position) tpar
     ,ALL_PART_KEY_COLUMNS pkey
     ,ALL_PART_TABLES      ptab
where tpar.owner=pkey.owner
and tpar.table_name=pkey.name
and tpar.owner=ptab.owner
and tpar.table_name=ptab.table_name
and pkey.object_type='TABLE';
```

The only issue is that you will be doing an implicit varchar2 to date conversion and I see no way of doing it otherwise.